# Plotting in R: Function with two vectors

Tags: r, vector

I want to plot a self-defined function in R using two vectors and an unknown variable. I thought about something like this:

```
# Define parameters
b<-c(1.70,4.70,7.60)
w<-c(0.38,0.44,0.50)

# Define function
k<-function(x){0.07*(w*(1-(x/-33)^(1/b)))^4}

# Plot
plot(k)
```

The goal is to plot the function, getting three lines. One line should contain the first pair of the b-vector/w-vector, the second line should contain the second pair and the third line should contain the last pair of the vectors. When I compile the code I get an error message:

> 1: In (x/-33)^(1/b) :   longer object length is not a multiple of
>   shorter object length 2: In w * (1 - (x/-33)^(1/b)) :   longer object
>   length is not a multiple of shorter object length

My idea was, that R wants to combine all the values from each vector with each other, which leads to the error message. Is there a way around the error?

Comment: Not directly related to the warning message, but `(x/-33)^(1/b)` is going to give you `NaN` for x > 0 and your values of `b`. Since `plot.function` plots values for x in [0, 1] by default, you're not going to see anything on your plot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `plot` needs a function that returns one value and not a vector.

One workaround would be to loop over your `b` and `w` values one by one and redefine your `k` function as you go. I've also changed your `k` function as it wasn't defined for the default parameters.

```
k <- function(b, w) {
  function(x){b*x+w}
}

plot2 <- function(k, b, w) {

  plot(k(b[1], w[1]))  
  for (i in 2:length(b)) {
    foo <- k(b[i], w[i])
    curve(foo, add = TRUE)
  }
}

plot2(k, b, w)
```

Comment: Obviously this can be improved a lot: lots of checks should be added (length(b) > 1, length(b) = length(w)...), also, it might be interesting to pass the additional parameters (b, w) with the three dot construct to ensure this would work with more flexibility...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this should give you the desired result.

```
b<-c(1.70,4.70,7.60)
w<-c(0.38,0.44,0.50)

curve((0.07*w[1])*((1-(x/(-33))^1/b[1])^4), from=0, to=20, type = 'l')

for(i in 2:length(b))
{
  curve((0.07*w[i])*((1-(x/(-33))^1/b[i])^4), from=0, to=20, add = TRUE)
}
```